# Laravel: use an url instead route in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5.4, I need to use an url instead route in a javascript file.

Right now I have a blade file with this code:

```
@section('after-scripts')
    {{ Html::script("https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js") }}
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route("admin.access.user.get") }}',
                type: 'post',
                data: {status: 1, trashed: false}
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: '{{config('access.users_table')}}.id'},
                {data: 'first_name', name: '{{config('access.users_table')}}.first_name'},                ],
            order: [[0, "asc"]],
            searchDelay: 100
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I want to take off the blade this  and save it as a normal .js file in my js assets. What should I do with the blade helpers like `route()`and `config()`?

Comment: An easy way is to output a global _(namespaced)_ object on your page with [`JavaScript::put(...)`](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize JavaScript variables in the blade file with the output of config and route before importing the script.

In Blade Template file

```
@section('after-scripts')
    {{ Html::script("https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js") }}
    <script>
        var accessurl = '{{ route("admin.access.user.get") }}';
        var config = '{{config('access.users_table')}}';
    </script>
    <script src="{{asset('path/to/jsfile.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
@endsection
```

In JavaScript file

```
$(function () {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: accessurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {status: 1, trashed: false}
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: config + '.id'},
            {data: 'first_name', name: config +'.first_name'},],
        order: [[0, "asc"]],
        searchDelay: 100
    });
});
```